# Rails 5 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed), but I have no validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to implement a `has_many :through` many to many form, but I'm having an issue submitting to the database. I have no field validations, which tells me it's complaining about the structure of the parameters hash more than anything.

The error is:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Expense expense categories expense must exist):

The parameter hash looks like this:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "expense"=>{"date"=>"2006/12/12", "amount"=>"234", "check_number"=>"234", "debit"=>"0", "notes"=>"234", "expense_expense_categories_attributes"=>{"1464029611137"=>{"amount"=>"234", "expense_category_id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Expense"}

One thing I notice is that it's not adding the `:expense_id` value into the junction table.  This should be done by the accepts_nested_attributes_for mechanism but it's not.  I'm starting to think this an issue with Rails 5 because I've had similar relationships and forms structured like this that works fine.  Do you guys see anything I'm missing?

here's my controller:

```
def create 

  @expense = Expense.new(expense_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @expense.save!
    @expenses = Expense.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order("created_at DESC")

      format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'Expense was successfully created.' }
      format.js {}
      format.json { render json: @expense, status: :created, location: @expense }
    else
      @expenses = Expense.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order("created_at DESC")
      format.html { render action: "index" }
      format.js {}
      format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def expense_params
  params.require(:expense).permit(:id, :date, :amount, :check_number, :debit, :notes, :amount, :expense_expense_categories_attributes => [:id, :amount, :expense_id , :expense_category_id, :_destroy])
end
```

Here are my models:

Expense

```
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payee
  monetize :amount_cents
  has_many :expense_expense_categories
  has_many :expense_categories, through: :expense_expense_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense_expense_categories,:allow_destroy => true

end
```

ExpenseCategory:

```
class ExpenseCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :expense_expense_categories
  has_many :expenses, through: :expense_expense_categories

end
```

ExpenseExpenseCategory

```
class ExpenseExpenseCategory < ApplicationRecord
  monetize :amount_cents
  belongs_to :expense
  belongs_to :expense_category

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense_category
end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @expense, html: { :class => "ui form segment" }, :remote => true do |f|%>

    <div class="field">

      <%= f.label :date%>
      <div class="ui small input">
      <%= f.date_field :date %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :amount %>
    <div class="ui small input">

      <%= f.text_field :amount %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :check_number %>
    <div class="ui small input">

      <%= f.text_field :check_number %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :debit %>
    <div class="ui small input">
      <%= f.check_box :debit %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :notes %>
    <div class="ui small input">
      <%= f.text_area :notes %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :expense_expense_categories do |builders| %>
      <%= render 'expense_expense_category_fields', :f => builders %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Category", f, :expense_expense_categories %>

  <%= f.submit class: "ui blue button" %>
```

expense_expense_category_fields.htnl.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%=f.label :amount%>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%=f.label :category%>
  <%= f.select :expense_category_id, ExpenseCategory.all.collect { |p| [p.category, p.id] } %>
</div>
<%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>

<%= link_to "Remove option", "#", :class => "remove_expense_expense_categories" %>
```

Here is the form data from the browser being submitted:

```
utf8:✓
expense[date]:2016-05-12
expense[amount]:23
expense[check_number]:23
expense[debit]:0
expense[notes]:
expense[expense_expense_categories_attributes][1464030986149][amount]:23
expense[expense_expense_categories_attributes][1464030986149][expense_category_id]:1
expense[expense_expense_categories_attributes][1464030986149][_destroy]:false
expense[expense_expense_categories_attributes][1464030991099][amount]:43
expense[expense_expense_categories_attributes][1464030991099][expense_category_id]:10
expense[expense_expense_categories_attributes][1464030991099][_destroy]:false
commit:Create Expense
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Rails is attempting to create ExpenseExpenseCategory before the expense has been created.  You must define; `:inverse_of` on the associations.

```
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payee
  monetize :amount_cents
  has_many :expense_expense_categories, inverse_of: :expense
  has_many :expense_categories, through: :expense_expense_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense_expense_categories,:allow_destroy => true

end

class ExpenseCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :expense_expense_categories, inverse_of: :expense_category
  has_many :expenses, through: :expense_expense_categories

end

class ExpenseExpenseCategory < ApplicationRecord
  monetize :amount_cents
  belongs_to :expense, inverse_of: :expense_expense_categories
  belongs_to :expense_category, inverse_of: :expense_expense_categories

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense_category
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses

Comment: It worked.  I'm not sure why someone down voted you lol.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a quick question.  In my rails 4 application `inverse_of:` wasn't required.  Is this a new requirement for Rails 5?

Comment: @ctilley79 I don't believe it is.  If the parent objects are new records then inverse_of is required.  Perhaps Rails parameterizes the class name to create a possible inverse_of value, which may be correct in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link
https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html

`inverse_of` didn't worked for me, I have to use `optional: true`  in `belongs_to` association.